# what book would you recommend for infopath development

Tags: infopath, books

Are there any books that you would recommend to a developer for infopath 2010 development for sharepoint 2010?

Comment: Converted to community wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a coworker has two books that she likes a lot for her InfoPath/SP development -

[Designing Forms for SharePoint and InfoPath: Using InfoPath Designer 2010](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321743601)

[InfoPath 2010 Cookbook: 101 Codeless Recipes for Beginners](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1456542761)

Answer (score 1):

[InfoPath with SharePoint 2010 How-To](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672333422)

[image]